# stacking numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to stack arrays horizontally, using numpy hstack, but can't get it to work. Instead, it all comes out in one list, instead of a 'matrix-looking' 2D array.

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array([0,2,-6,4,1])
y_bool = y > 0
y_bool = [1 if l == True else 0 for l in y_bool] #convert to decimals for classification
y_range = range(0,len(y))
print y
print y_bool
print y_range
print np.hstack((y,y_bool,y_range))
```

Prints this:

```
[ 0  2 -6  4  1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[ 0  2 -6  4  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  2  3  4]
```

How do I instead get the last line to look like this:

```
[0 0 0
 2 1 1
-6 0 2
 4 1 3]
```

Comment: Aside: you can simply use `y_bool = (y > 0) * 1` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a 2D array, do:

```
print np.transpose(np.array((y, y_bool, y_range)))
# [[ 0  0  0]
#  [ 2  1  1]
#  [-6  0  2]
#  [ 4  1  3]
#  [ 1  1  4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, close enough h is for horizontal/column wise, if you check its help, you will see under *See Also*

```
vstack : Stack arrays in sequence vertically (row wise).
dstack : Stack arrays in sequence depth wise (along third axis).
concatenate : Join a sequence of arrays together.
```

Edit: First thought `vstack` does it, but it would be if `np.vstack(...).T` or `np.dstack(...).squeeze()`. Other then that the "problem" is that the arrays are 1D and you want them to act like 2D, so you could do:

```
print np.hstack([np.asarray(a)[:,np.newaxis] for a in (y,y_bool,y_range)])
```

the `np.asarray` is there just in case one of the variables is a list. The `np.newaxis` makes them 2D to make it clearer what happens when concatenating.

Comment: For the OP example, `np.dstack(...).squeeze()`.